# Does weak convergance in $H_{0}^{1}(0,1)$ implies strong convergance in $C(0,1)$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

I was wondering whether one can prove the following statement

$(x_{n})\subset H_{0}^{1}(0,1)$ and $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ weakly $\Rightarrow x_{n}\rightarrow x$ in $C(0,1)$?

As far as I know, if $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ in $H_{0}^{1}(0,1)$ then follows the convergance in $C(0,1)$ because $H_{0}^{1}(0,1)\subset C(0,1)$. But now, only weak convergance is given.

Comment: We actually have the (continuous) embedding $H_0^1(0,1)\subset C^{0,1/2}(0,1)$ and this last space is compactly embedded in $C(0,1)$ (Use Arzela-Ascoli to see this).

Comment: Okay, but does it have antyhing in common with weak convergance in $H_{0}^{1}(0,1)$?

Comment: Well, a compact embedding sends weakly convergent sequences to norm convergent ones, so...

Comment: ... so I need to study compact embbedings harder - thank you for your hints.